# How do I change extensions of all files in a folder to one common extension when all the files have different extensions?

Tags: command-line, file-format, rename

I have a grader for COCI (a competitive programming contest) that reads input files (`txt[number].in`), compiles and runs a code (`txt.cpp`) and matches the result with an output file (`txt[number].out`).
The problem is, COCI problem's input files have format (`txt.in.1`), (`txt.in.2`), (`txt.in.3`) etc and similar names for output files.

I need to change the extensions of the input files from `txt.in.[number]` to `txt[number].in`. (Need to do the same for the output files as well)

Can anyone help me with this?

I'm currently using 13.04 Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the terminal, I think this is the easiest way:

```
mmv -v "*.in.*" "#1#2.in"
```

Here is a test:

```
$ ls
txt.in.1  txt.in.2  txt.in.3
$ mmv -v "*.in.*" "#1#2.in"
txt.in.1 -> txt1.in : done
txt.in.2 -> txt2.in : done
txt.in.3 -> txt3.in : done
$ ls
txt1.in  txt2.in  txt3.in
```

By default, `mmv` is not installed in Ubuntu, but you can install it from terminal using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mmv
```

See [`man mmv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/mln.1.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply. I'm away from home and hardly have access to internet and ubuntu. But this looks like its just what I want. I'll get back to as soon as I get to try this.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again.
I just changed the question a bit. Since I dont know how mmv works, I need your help to know how I have to make the change.

Comment: @Labib666 Ok, see my new edits. But keep in mind: It's not a good practice to change your question after you received your answer. Use [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button if you have new questions.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll try not to do such mistakes from the next time. I'm fairly new here. So, just learning from errors.

Comment: @Labib666 Ok. So, have you seen my new edits at the answer?

Comment: Yes I have seen the changes.
I'll need try them out. May take some time for that. 
I'll tell you about it when I do. :)

Comment: I still have not got the chance to try the new commands. I've seen them and will let you know the results. :)
Meanwhile, It would be helpful if you tell me how the commands would look if I was changing extension of txt.in.[number][alphabet] to txt[number][alphabet].in. 
I just heard that there were extensions like these as well. :(

Comment: @Labib666 You can use exactly the same command to change files from `txt.in.[number][alphabet]` to `txt[number][alphabet].in`.

Comment: It works! I just have to put the lines in my script now! :D
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

If it is okay that a `file.in.1` becomes `file.in.1.in`, then this will do

```
rename 's/$/.in/' *
```

If you think the two *in*'s are ugly, then do

```
rename 's/\.in(\.\d+)$/$1.in/' *
```

Pass the `-n` option to perform a dry run.

Comment: You can make it a little simpler than that I think e.g. `s/(\.in)(\.\d+)/$2$1/`. Also for safety it's good practice to mark the end of the option list i.e. `rename -nv -- 's/(\.in)(\.\d+)/$2$1/' *` (just in case there happen to be any files starting with `-`)

Comment: @steeldriver Good point, the regexp isn't pinned at ^, so the first can also be reduced to `'s/$/.in/'`. And the second can be simplified even further. Will fix the solution.

Comment: I knew this one. Unfortunately .in  and .out files need to have same names. So it doesn't really help. Thanks for trying though :)

Answer (score 0):

This script will *copy* all files in the working dir, that match *.in.*

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(ls *.in.*)
do
    target=$(echo ${i} | awk -F'.' '{ print $1$3"."$2 }')
    cp ${i} ${target}
done
```

Comment: I'll get back to you after I try it on my computer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

A version using `rename` that works for your revised format would be

```
rename -- 's/(\.in|\.out)\.(\d+)/$2$1/' *
```

e.g.

```
$ ls
txt.in.1  txt.in.2  txt.in.3  txt.out.1  txt.out.2  txt.out.3
$
$ rename -nv -- 's/(\.in|\.out)\.(\d+)/$2$1/' *
txt.in.1 renamed as txt1.in
txt.in.2 renamed as txt2.in
txt.in.3 renamed as txt3.in
txt.out.1 renamed as txt1.out
txt.out.2 renamed as txt2.out
txt.out.3 renamed as txt3.out
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. :)
It would be helpful if you tell me how the commands would look if I was changing extension of txt.in.[number][alphabet] to txt[number][alphabet].in. 
I just heard that there were extensions like these as well. :(

Comment: Well you could change the `\d+` (one or more digits) by `\w+` (one or more from the set [a-zA-Z0-9_] in any order) although that would match things like `2c3`, `aBa` as well; if you need to match EXACTLY one or more digits optionally followed by one or more alphabetical letters, change `(\d+)` to `(\d+([[:alpha:]]+)?)` or `([[:digit:]]+([[:alpha:]]+)?)` - you should probably look up some information about **perl regular expressions** and try to figure out exactly what you need yourself